# No terms and conditions on service provider website

Tags: contracts, training, education

I am self-paying for a series of  qualifications to improve my employment prospects. The cost is considerable and states 'no refunds, cancellations or re-schedules'.  I then asked the merchant for full terms and conditions and was told they did not have any.
Is this a red flag or is it common practice?

Comment: **Is this a red flag?** - Yes.

Comment: It sounds like their policy is essentially, “no refunds, cancellations or re-schedules”, which isn’t that unusual with remote training classes. You should determine if there are other service providers that have different terms

Comment: I can understand "no refunds, cancellations" because of financial concerns. But, no re-schedules is unacceptable. You could have unexpected schedule conflict. Then you lose money. Yes, it is a red flag.

Comment: Not having even minimal boilerplate terms and conditions implies that they haven't thought about their business too hard. Apparently they aren't asking you not to record these classes or not to have a bunch of other people sit in on the call either?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's a red flag.

Having said that, the whole online certification industry with a few exceptions is full of flags and the qualifications while better than nothing are of dubious value.

It's best to look for those qualifications which are recognised internationally and sought after by employers. Microsoft, Cisco etc,. are examples, I don't mean you should look for those in particular.